# Stop to VS Code from breaking print statements - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do I stop VS Code from adding line breaks into my print statements? it prevents my code from running correctly on my ubuntu instance.

```
print(f'Error fetching ticket ID {
                      ticket_id}: {response.status_code}')
```

I tried making the word wrap setting 500, made no difference. On save it still breaks onto two lines.

Comment: Breaking after a curly brace like that makes a lot more sense for C than Python.  I suspect you've got VS Code configured to apply some sort of C formatting to your code.

Comment: This is not the behavior I see in VSCode. Do you have a formatter like black active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable formatting on save. Go to settings, search for 'format on save' and make sure that box is unchecked. You can also go adjust the settings of whatever formatter VS Code is using for python. If it's not the default python formatter, that might be the issue.[image]